# How do you get more Boosts in the Steam Grand Prix?

Tags: steam, steam-grand-prix

The [Steam Grand Prix](https://store.steampowered.com/grandprix) has lots of weird and unintuitive rules. You can use Boosts to spend up to 1000 distance points to make your team go faster, but the number of Boosts available seems limited, and I don't see any way to earn more Boosts once they've ran out.

[image: 4 boosts remaining]

Is it possible to gain more Boosts? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a limited number of Boosts, the page was edited to clarify that:

[image: The new boost button, with no mention of total boosts]

Answer (score 1):

#### Your number of boosts is determined by your ( Boost Capacity / 1000 ) with the remainder counting as 1 more boost.

- If you have 5000 boost capacity, then the maximum amount of Boosts you can use is 5 (5000/1000).
- If you have 5250 boost capacity, then the maximum amount of Boosts you can use is 6 (5000/1000, remainder 250 rounded up).

You gain more possible boosts by simply having more Boost Capacity. You can get boost capacity by:

- Buying games. $1 = 100 points added to your total capacity.
- Participating in the Grand Prix each day. You get an additional 100 boost capacity this way.

You gain the ability to USE boosts by getting Boost Points.  Boost Points are earned by unlocking Achievements in Steam Games or completing challenges in participating Grand Prix Sale games.

It is important to note that your Boost Capacity will ALWAYS go down by the number of Boost Points used in your last boost. If your Boost Capacity is 5000, but you only have 4500 boost points to spend, your:

- # of boosts is still 5, (4 x 1000 distance boosts, 1x 500 distance boost)
- capacity will drop by 4500 points to 500 if you spend all your points

Thus, in order to gain more boosts, you need both more Boost Capacity, and Boost Points. Going back to the previous example, assume you have 5000 Boost Capacity.

- If you have 4000 points, then the MAX usable boosts is 4, while the MAX possible boosts is 5.
- If you have 4724 points, then the MAX usable boosts is 5, while the MAX possible boosts is 5.
- If you have 200 points, then the MAX usable boosts is 1, while the MAX possible boosts is 5.

Comment: I don't see anything in this answer stating how to get more Boosts, just how to earn distance points.

Comment: @Wrigglenite The number of boosts you get is determined by how much boost points you have in your boost meter, which is covered in the answer and the FAQ page on the Grand Prix page.

Comment: Again, I don't know how you're getting to this conclusion. There is only a limited number of boosts available, and I don't see any way of earning more boosts. If you could point me specifically to where this is mentioned, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Your number of boosts is based on your boost capacity + boost points.  The maximum amount of resources that a boost can conusme is 1000 distance + 25 nitro points.  The larger your capacity, the more "boosts" you can have, and the more points you have, the more actual boosts you can use.

Comment: There is a limited number of Boosts available regardless of points, see my edit.

Comment: @Wrigglenite And that amount of boosts is available by your current capacity. You need points in order to boost distance, but you also need capacity to hold more points to perform more boosts. Remember that Steam has retroactively given you a specific amount of boost capacity based on your account's prior transaction history.

Comment: You can boost with as little as 100 points, so there is actually no correlation between number of boosts and point capacity.

Comment: Your number of boosts is basically capacity/1000.  Yes, you can boost with as little as 100 points, but if your capacity is 5000, that's still 5 boosts possible.  Even if you consume

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to note here is, that boosting reduces your capacity by the amount of points/distance you boosted.

Say your current capacity is 1500 and you boost for 1000 distance, your capacity is now 500. Once you are at 0 capacity, you can not boost anymore.

To get more boosts now, you have to either wait for the next day (you get a free 100 capacity each day you participate) or buy games during the sale, every dollar you spend amounts to 100 capacity (this varies for different currencies, 1€ = 121 capacity for example).

Comment: There is a limited number of Boosts available regardless of points, see my edit.

Comment: Not quite sure what to make of that without seeing your current points/capacity.

Comment: Considering you can boost with as little as 100 points and my capacity is over 3000, it's clear to see that there is no correlation between capacity and number of boosts. I could use all 4 of my boosts without even spending 1000 points.

Comment: From my understanding, the number of boosts it shows is just the capacity / 1000 and rounded up to 1, so if you currently have 3600 capacity and spend the 580 distance from your screenshot you would still be at 3020 capacity and it should still say 4 boosts remaining. I can not confirm this right now unfortunately so I will wait with adding that info to my answer.